# iTunes Connect: Where did the vendor id go?

Tags: app-store-connect

As of yesterday, Monday 2/17/2014, the iTunes Connect site changed.  I can no longer find the vendor id on any of the iTunes connect pages.  I find the Apple ID fine for each app, but I need the vendor id, not the app id.

We have been running the autoingestion tool for years to pull download numbers for our clients' apps.  As of yesterday I can no longer find this vendor id for the autoingestion tool.

Can somebody point me to where I can find this id?

Answer (score 14):

With the last update on [iTunnes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com), in the Sales and Trends section, pressing on the top 
right menu that shows "Top Content" can access to the [Reports entry (direct link).](https://reportingitc2.apple.com/reports.html)

There you can see the "Vendor" selector, pressing on it you can see the Details of the vendor with the following format:

```
VendorName - VendorId
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This was the only one I could get to work, clicking your "direct link" above took me right to my Vendor ID! Thank you

Answer (score 13):

There is another way with the existing reportingitc2 URL. Choose "Reports" from the top left menu (Where default is "Top Content"). From the form that will be shown, choose monthly report and download. The downloaded file will be of format S_M_(VendorID)_TIMEPERIOD.TXT

Comment: this one is correct - super useful answer since who knows when the olde reportingitc.apple.com site will disappear.

Comment: The only one that easily work. All other answers are outdated. Thank you!

Comment: Nowadays, I've seen my vendor Id at the [report page](https://reportingitc2.apple.com/reports.html), at the vendor select it says "Name - Vendor id". I haven't find the vendor id at the download file, I only have seen two dates. (as [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23195320/2412686) says)

Comment: In case something someday changes, I just want to say that the filename of the downloadable sales reports which are available from the Payments and Financial Reports screen has the Vendor ID in the filename as well. (So it's in two places at the moment)  (VendorID)_Timeperiod_Region.txt.gz

Answer (score 3):

Read on Apple Dev Forum

"Removing the numeral 2 in the url reverts back to the old interface."

so visit 
"https://reportingitc.apple.com/index.html" instead of 
"https://reportingitc2.apple.com/index.html"

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/219844?tstart=0

Its works but I don't know how long it will work for.

Comment: You can only go to the reports page now. https://reportingitc2.apple.com/reports.html